# Design a REST API in which a search request can take parameters for multiple Queries

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have to design a REST API in which a **search request can take parameters for multiple Queries** ( i.e. when the client make a call using this API, he should be able to send parameters to form **multiple queries**).

We have an existing API where we are using **GET** and it takes multiple parameters which together forms a single Query and then this API call returns the response for this query.
e.g. currently I can pass firstName, lastName, age etc in the request and then get back the person.

But now I have to enhance this service(or have a separate service) where I should be able to send parameters like firstName1, lastName1, age1 to search person1 ; firstName2, lastName2, age2 to search person2 and so on.

Should I use **POST** for the new API and then send list of parameters(params for query1, params for query2 and so on)?
Or is there a better approach.

We are using Spring Boot for REST implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here will be do **POST** and then return a **JSON** object with all the details of the `Person` in an array.

That way it will be faster and you would not have to deal with long urls for **GET**.

Also GET has limitations regarding the length of the request whereas there is no such limitation in case of **POST**.

Comment: @RohitGupta If this answer has helped, can you please accept the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use POST because GET is good for 2,3 parameter but when you have a set of parameter or object then POST is Good.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to give a right answer here. In general sending a **GET** request does have the advantage that you can leverage caching easily on a HTTP level, e.g. by using products like varnish, nginx, etc. But if you already can forsee that your URL including all params you'll have to send a **POST** request to make it work in all Browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

RESTfull architecture should respect the principle of *addressability*.

Since multiple users can be accessed through a unique request, then ideally this group of user should get an address, which would identify it as a resource. 
However I understand that in the real world, URIs have a limited length ([maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)). A POST request would indeed work well, but we lose the benefit of addressability.

Another way would be to expose a new resource : group,. 
Lets suppose that your current model is something like this :

```
.../users/{id}
.../users/search?{arg1}={val1};{arg2}={val2}
```

You could eventually do something like :

```
.../users/groups/
.../users/groups/{id}
.../users/search?group={id}
```

(explanation below)

then you could split your research in two :

- first a POST on .../users/groups/ with, as proposed by other response, a JSON description of the search parameters. This request could scan the .../users/groups/ directory, and if this set of parameters exists, return the corresponding address .../users/groups/{id}. (for performance issues you could for instance define {id} with a first part which would give the number of users requested).
- Then you could make a request for this group with a GET with something like this : .../users/search?group={id}.

This approach would be a bit more complex to implement, but is more consistent with the resource oriented paradigm.